# How to integrate |z| dz?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

As the title says, how do we integrate $|z|dz$ on a straight line on the complex plane? Suppose that I've already known the parametrization. If it were on reals, we would break the integral down to multiple parts where z changes sign, but how do I do that on the complex plane?

Is it just simply the formula for absolute value (square root of the sum of the squares of real and imaginary parts)?

Comment: How do you integrate an arbitrary (but, say, continuous) function $f$ over some path in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It won't be finite if taken on whole of the line. Just evaluate length of $z$, ie. the distance to origin of your $r(t)$ of your parameterized path. It will be a real valued function integrated against arc-length of your parameterized path.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Along the straight-line path from $z_1$ to $z_2$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{z_1}^{z_2}|z|\,dz&=\int_0^1 |z_1+(z_2-z_1)t|\,(z_2-z_1)\,dt\\\\
&=(z_2-z_1)\int_0^1 \sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2-z_1|^2t^2+2\text{Re}(z_1^*(z_2-z_1))t}\,dt
\end{align}$$